# Calculate time difference in minutes

Tags: python, time, pandas

I'm reading a text file which has time(hours and minutes) and IP addresses. Then I want to get the time differences and do some activity for every 5 minutes. 
Following code does not calculate the time difference.

sample text file:

```
06:03 65.55.215.62
06:04 157.56.92.152
06:04 66.249.74.175
06:05 173.199.116.171
```

code:

```
time_ip = []
for line in open('minutes'):
    time_ip.append(line.split(' '))    

df = pandas.DataFrame(time_ip)
df['tvalue'] = df[0]
df['delta'] = (df['tvalue']-df['tvalue'])
```

Comment: `df['tvalue']-df['tvalue']` == 0, if `df[0]` is a number.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-deltas   this has some instructions

Comment: @Elazar IT gives the same error...TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: That's because you read an `str` from the file. maybe you want `t, ip = line.split(' '); t = int(t); time_ip.append([t, ip]);`

Comment: This is actually incredibly tricky to do without the date part, as well as ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) to read a csv into a DataFrame:

```
In [1]: df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep='\s+', header=None, names=['time', 'ip'])

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
    time               ip
0  06:03     65.55.215.62
1  06:04    157.56.92.152
2  06:04    66.249.74.175
3  06:05  173.199.116.171
```

Pandas doesn't (yet) have any built in time object, and doing this in python isn't the easy... you can make the time column of time objects:

```
In [3]: df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.time(*map(int, x.split(':'))))

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
       time               ip
0  06:03:00     65.55.215.62
1  06:04:00    157.56.92.152
2  06:04:00    66.249.74.175
3  06:05:00  173.199.116.171
```

*Not least because you can't do [arithmetic on datetime.time objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.resolution).* At any rate, I think you're going to get into a sticky situation by not having the year/month/day here too, for one thing, how to deal with the midnight?

So let's start again, assuming you had a datetime...

```
In [5]: df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep='\s+', header=None, names=['time', 'ip'])

In [6]: df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])  # let's use todays

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
                 time               ip
0 2013-06-12 06:03:00     65.55.215.62
1 2013-06-12 06:04:00    157.56.92.152
2 2013-06-12 06:04:00    66.249.74.175
3 2013-06-12 06:05:00  173.199.116.171
```

Then you can grab out the difference using a [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
In [8]: df['time'].shift()
Out[8]:
0                   NaT
1   2013-06-12 06:03:00
2   2013-06-12 06:04:00
3   2013-06-12 06:04:00
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [9]: d['time'] - df['time'].shift()
Out[9]:
0        NaT
1   00:01:00
2   00:00:00
3   00:01:00
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Much easier. :)

Comment: Why this error?AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_datetime' @Andy Hayden

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage which version of pandas are you using? You need to upgrade to the latest stable version. :)

Comment: df['time'].shift() produces the same output with IPs? @Andy Hayden

Comment: I don't follow you, the exact output is seen above... ?

Comment: IP column is still there?After performing shift()

Comment: The shift isn't inplace, you can set it to your column with `df['delta'] = ...`, yes the ip will still be there.

Comment: df['delta'] = (df['time']-df['time'].shift()).fillna(0) this works fine, and gives the difference as 00:01:00. How to get the minute difference(01)? @Andy Hayden

Comment: see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-deltas, getting the minute depends in your numpy version. also see the cookbook under miscellaneous for more examples of this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module

```
import datetime
with open('minutes', 'r') as myfile:
    times = myfile.read().split()[::2]
dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%H:%M') for i in times]
differences = [j-i for i, j in zip(dates[:-1], dates[1:])]
print [divmod(i.seconds, 60)[0] for i in differences]
```

Prints:

```
[1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: for line in open('minutes'):
    times = line.split()[::2]
    dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%H:%M')for i in times]
    differences = [j-i for i, j in zip(dates[:-1], dates[1:])]
    print [divmod(i.seconds, 60) for i in differences]............this just print an emty array @Haidro

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage Updating

Comment: For the simple file this is fine, but for the large data file the output is so confused, how to print this line by line?

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage I'll explain the output. The first item in the tuple is the amount of minutes of difference. The second one is the amount of second, if there was a remainder (i.e, if there were 61 seconds)

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage I've changed the output so now it just returns the minute difference

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> end = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> start = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> diff
datetime.timedelta(0, 7, 424199)
>>> diff = start - end
>>> divmod(diff.days * 86400 + diff.seconds, 60)
(0, 7) # 0 minutes, 7 seconds
```